# Change gender dropdown to radio button in magento

Tags: magento

Today i started working in registration form in magento site. As you know by default it's having `gender drop down`. I need to change that to `checkbox`.

So far i went to `register.phtml` file, and tried to add `<input type="radio" ...../>` select files, but this didn't worked.

Did anyone know how to solve this !
please give me some suggestions to so this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento uses widgets on registration form. In fact in template register.phtml you can see lines:

```
<?php $_gender = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_gender') ?>
<?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
    <li><?php echo $_gender->setGender($this->getFormData()->getGender())->toHtml() ?></li>
<?php endif ?>
```

This particular widget can be found in `template/customer/widget` directory. So in order to change select into radio buttons, copy it (template) to your theme and modify, e.g.:

```
<div class="input-box">
    <label><?php echo $this->__('Gender'); ?></label>
    <?php $options = Mage::getResourceSingleton('customer/customer')->getAttribute('gender')->getSource()->getAllOptions();?>
    <?php $value = $this->getGender();?>
    <?php foreach ($options as $option):?>
    <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('gender')?>" value="<?php echo $option['value'] ?>"<?php if ($option['value'] == $value) echo ' selected="selected"' ?> /><?php echo $option['label'] ?>
    <br />
    <?php endforeach;?>
</div>
```

Hope didn't make any typo.

Comment: Could you please help to solve this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595547/convert-dropdown-to-selection-boxes-with-color

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget the validation!

```
<div class="input-box">
    <?php
        $options = Mage::getResourceSingleton('customer/customer')->getAttribute('gender')->getSource()->getAllOptions();
        $value = $this->getGender();
        $_last = count($options);
        $_index = 0;
    ?>
    <?php foreach ($options as $option):?>
        <?php if($option['value'] != ''): ?>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('gender')?>-<?php echo $option['value'] ?>"
                   class="radio<?php if ($this->isRequired() && $_index == $_last - 1):?> validate-one-required<?php endif; ?>"
                   type="radio" title="<?php echo $option['label'] ?>"
                   value="<?php echo $option['value'] ?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('gender')?>"
                   <?php if ($option['value'] == $value) echo ' checked="checked"' ?>>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('gender')?>-<?php echo $option['value'] ?>">
                <?php echo $option['label'] ?>
            </label>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php $_index++; ?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</div>
```